# Are fields of a type the same in different Language Operating System

Tags: c#, field, notifyicon

I am creating an application with support for multilingual operating system .
At one place in the application I am using following line of code.

```
Type t = typeof(System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon);
BindingFlags hidden = BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance;
t.GetField("text", hidden).SetValue(notifyIcon, notificationToolTip);
```

Will it run smoothly on different language Operating system , or I have to change the required fields for different language. 
For example , for french operating system I have to make the following changes.

```
t.GetField("texte",hidden),SetValue(notifyIcon,notificationToopTip);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, the names of members are not dependent on the language settings of the operating system. When you declare a class like this:

```
public class Foo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

... it's not like the compiler automatically translates that into `Nom` in French etc.

On the other hand, the names of non-public members *can* change between different versions of the library - the whole point of them being non-public is that you're not meant to use them, which means the library author is entirely at liberty to change them later. *That's* the aspect of your code which is brittle - not the internationalization aspect.

Comment: @ Jon Skeet I am talking about different language operating system,like Windows installed in french or some other language and not in English.

Comment: @G10, Jon Skeet's response is pertinent to that also.

Comment: @g10: It doesn't matter at all. The program code still isn't going to be translated. (Think about it: when you declare a field do you really expect that something's going to automatically translate it?)